# C++ iterating over tuple in fold operator

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I have a function that takes a variable number of objects, each of them has a function that can call a callback with some value. I need to call that function and collect the values in a tuple. It is complicated by the fact that the actual function calls the callback asynchronously, so I can't get away with a simple wrapper that converts it into a traditional returning function.

Something like this works, as long as there are no duplicate types:

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
    T T_;
public:
    Foo( T t ) : t_( t ) {}

    template<class Func>
    int callMe( Func func )
    {
        func( t_ );
        return 0; // this is some sort of callback ID
    }
}

template<class... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> collect( Foo<Args>... args )
{
    std::tuple<Args...> result;
    std::vector<int> callbacks
    {
        args.callMe( [&result]( const Args& x )
        {
            std::get<Args>( result ) = x;
        } )...
    };
    return result;
}

// returns tuple<int, double, char>( 1, 2.0, '3' )
auto res = collect( Foo( 1 ), Foo( 2.0 ), Foo( '3' ) );
```

But if I want to allow repeated types, I'd have to introduce an integer sequence somehow. Is there a way to do it without ugly helper functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::apply` to "iterate" over the tuple:

```
template<class... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> collect( Foo<Args>... args )
{
    std::tuple<Args...> result;

    std::apply([&](auto&&... xs)
    {   
        (args.callMe([&](const auto& x)
        {
            xs = x;
        }), ...);
   }, result);

    return result;
}
```

I am having trouble getting compilers to agree with the code above, though: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n53PSd

- g++ ICEs
- clang++ reports a nonsensical error

---

You can introduce an integer sequence in scope in C++20 using a *lambda expression*:

```
template<class... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> collect( Foo<Args>... args )
{
    std::tuple<Args...> result;

    [&]<auto... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        ( args.callMe( [&result]( const Args& x )
        {
            std::get<Is>( result ) = x;
        } ), ... );
    }(std::make_index_sequence_for<Args...>{});

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I edited the question, the actual `callMe` function returns a callback ID that needs to be kept as well.

Comment: You can just add a `callbacks.emplace_back(args.callMe(/*...*/))` in the fold expression in my examples to make them work with your updated use case.

Comment: Oh gotcha, I can also return the result from `apply` and use it in the initializer list I believe. Thanks, that should work!

Comment: @riv: here's a workaround if your compiler complains as well: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MVwl-6

Comment: VS2017 seems to have no issues. I did it a little differently, using a vector initializer list, which also removes the need for fold operator: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fVcm5b

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this helper function (`visit`) is ugly or not, at least it looks good to me.

```
template<class T>
T visit(Foo<T>& t){
    T result;
    t.callMe([&](const T& x){result=x;});
    return result;
}

template<class... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> collect( Foo<Args>... args )
{
    return std::tuple{visit(args)...};
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, because the actual `callMe` function returns other stuff I need to keep.

Comment: @riv maybe you should update the question to contain some example?

Comment: I did. The other answer seems to work for my case, thanks anyway though.

Comment: @riv it depends on what you want, the `callbacks` in your example may be independent or not. the `visit` may be rewrite to match it. Anyway, it's good you find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couple of lambdas to achieve what you want:

```
template<class... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> collect( Foo<Args>... args )
{
    return {
        [&args]{
            Args t;
            args.callMe([&t](const Args& x){ t = x; });
            return t;
        }()...
    };
}
```

Comment: I edited the comment, I need to preserve the return values from callMe. Also, the actual code is async, so that wouldn't work anyway.